# Kusama parachain auction scheduling

Tags: parachain, kusama, auctions

Is Kusama parachain auction scheduling broken?

Looking at [Auction schedule](https://guide.kusama.network/docs/learn-auction#auction-schedule), the current action should be **`65`**.

> Auction #65 is in progress on Kusama, which started on Tue Dec 13 2022 and ends on Mon Dec 19 2022.

But when checking https://polkadot.js.org/apps it shows that kusama is still in action **`62`** and is inactive:

[image: kusama auction]

Auction **`65`** was supposed to start at block `15724800` but the [scheduled task](https://kusama.subscan.io/block/15724800?tab=event&&event=15724800-57) seems to have failed.

[image: scheduled task]

The image below was taken yesterday on the `scheduler` tab.

[image: scheduled task]

Comment: This seems to be a known issue. The Kusama team is looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auction should had started at the beginning of LP26 and it did not, it failed. The reason behind it is that with the new OpenGov the origin of the extrinsics changed and this one particularly is failing. I should've been solved with the emergency patch of 0.9.34, but unfortunately that's not the case, and it's currently under investigation.